# How, in SQL Server can I SUBTRACT TWO DATETIMES to get a precise DECIMAL result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand `datediff` only gives you an integer, is there an alternative that gives you a decimal result of the difference between two datetimes?

Would the following be sufficient/accurate:

```
CAST(DateA- DateB AS decimal(7 , 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can determine granularity of the int it returns - it can be years, quarters, months weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds... I think that's all of them.

Here's an example returning the difference in seconds then converting to minutes, hours, etc:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
set @end = getdate()

declare @deltaSeconds int

set @deltaSeconds = DATEDIFF( ss, @start, @end )

select @deltaSeconds Seconds, @deltaSeconds / 60.0 [Minutes], @deltaSeconds / 60.0 / 60.0 [Hours], @deltaSeconds / 60.0 / 60.0 / 24.0 [Days]
```

Comment: Thanks, would the simple 'CAST(DateA- DateB AS decimal(7 , 2))' not suffice?

Comment: Yes, if you want the result in days, that would appear to be fine.